# Highlight a section of the plot in a plotly graph

Tags: python, plotly

I plot the below dataframe using plotly. I am trying to highlight the area (using a circle or rectangle) if the value of dist1 is < 0.5 and value of dist2 is > 15. Not sure is there a way to achieve this using plotly.

```
 import plotly.express as px
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 for i in range(len(values)):
    df_results = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values[i][1])
    df_results.columns = ['value','dist1','dist2']
    plt.figure(figsize=[15,7])
    fig = px.scatter(df_results, x="dist1", y="dist2")
    fig.show()
```

Sample dataframe:

```
 value   dist1    dist2
 A-0     0.4      16.0
 A-1     0.3      18.0
 A-2     0.9      5.0
 A-4     1.0      2.0
 A-5     0.2      18.0
```

After plotting the above dataframe, would like to highlight the region where  dist1 is less than 0.5 and dist2 is greater than 15.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this function ? `plt.axvspan(3, 6, color='blue', alpha=0.5)` ?

Comment: @abdou_dev: i tried it, did not work

Comment: you describe data without providing sample.  Do you want plotly or matplotlib?  why are you trying to mix the two?  they are different libraries / object models

Comment: @RobRaymond: I tried using both the libraries. For matplotlib, I tried with axvspan, it did not work as expected. Then, trying with plotly now.

Comment: ok - it would be far simpler if you provide sample data rather than leave it to answer to simulate it

Comment: @RobRaymond: added the sample data

Answer (score 1):

- the simplest way is to *color* points in scatter.  Using a straight forward mask for this
- to shade an area, you can create a shape https://plotly.com/python/shapes/

  - have created a dataframe to calculate the *x0, y0, x1, y1* coordinates
  - not sure if you have multiple areas for this, hence have created shapes for any set of contiguous areas

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df_results = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """ value   dist1    dist2
 A-0     0.4      16.0
 A-1     0.3      18.0
 A-2     0.9      5.0
 A-4     1.0      2.0
 A-5     0.2      18.0"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
)


# order is important for finding contiguous area
df_results = df_results.sort_values(["dist1", "dist2"]).reset_index(drop=True)

mask = df_results["dist1"].lt(0.5) & df_results["dist2"].gt(15)
fig = px.scatter(df_results, x="dist1", y="dist2", color=mask)

for r in (
    df_results.loc[mask]
    .reset_index() # for finding contigouous rows
    .assign(area=lambda d: ((d["index"] - d["index"].shift()) != 1).cumsum())
    .groupby("area")
    .agg(
        minx=("dist1", "min"),
        maxx=("dist1", "max"),
        miny=("dist2", "min"),
        maxy=("dist2", "max"),
    )
    .iterrows()
):
    fig.add_shape(
        type="rect",
        x0=r[1]["minx"],
        x1=r[1]["maxx"],
        y0=r[1]["miny"],
        y1=r[1]["maxy"],
        fillcolor="green",
        opacity=0.2,
    )


fig
```

[image]